# Find and return first match in nested lists in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Consider the following two classes:

```
class ObjectA(val objectBs: List<ObjectB>,
              val otherFields: Any)

class ObjectB(val key: String,
              val otherFields: Any)
```

The task is to find and return the first ObjectB with a certain key in a List of ObjectA.

Just achieving the goal is simple enough, but doing it nicely and efficiently seems rather tricky. I can't find anything like a "firstIn" or "findIn" function that would allow me to return another type than ObjectA when iterating on a list of ObjectA.

I have a few approaches, one of which looks pretty nice, but is very inefficient:

```
listOfA.mapNotNull { 
    it.objectBs.firstOrNull { 
        item -> item.key == wantedKey
   } 
}.firstOrNull()
```

The obvious inefficiency of this code is that it will not stop iterating through listOfA when it has found a match (and there can only be one match, just to be clear).
Approaches using filter or find have similar problems, requiring redundant iterations through at least one list of ObjectB.

Is there something in kotlins standard library that would cover such a use case?

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe sequence can help. Could you try `list.asSequence()`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want an elegant solution you can just do a `flatMap` like this:

```
val result: ObjectB? = listOfA.flatMap { it.objectBs }.firstOrNull { it.key == "myKey" }
```

If you want the efficiency you can do something like this:

```
val result: ObjectB? = objectAs.firstOrNull {
    it.objectBs.map(ObjectB::key).contains("myKey")
}?.objectBs?.firstOrNull { it.key == "myKey" }
```

You can also wrap these in an `Optional` and put it in a function so the users of this operation can have a clean API:

```
fun List<ObjectA>.findFirstObjectB(key: String): Optional<ObjectB> {
    return Optional.ofNullable(firstOrNull {
        it.objectBs.map(ObjectB::key).contains(key)
    }?.objectBs?.firstOrNull { it.key == key })
}
```

Comment: The second solution doesn't traverse all items, and will stop on the first matching item.

Comment: No, it is not, as I have said.

Comment: @whomever downvorted: care to explain?

Comment: The second piece of code doesn't traverse all items, but it has to search for the key twice in a potentially large list of ObjectB. I guess it would take some testing to see if it is actually more efficient than the flatmap solution. That one does traverse all ObjectA, but doesn't perform any operations on them, which I would intuitively expect to be faster than running redundant string comparisons.

Comment: Asymptotically speaking, the first has `n` * `m` complexity, where `n` is the number of `ObjectA`s, and `m` is the number of `ObjectB`s within an `ObjectA`. The second one has `n` * `2m` complexity. It trades the cost of traversing *B*s twice for short-circuiting when traversing *A*s.

Answer (score 11):

By converting all the nested elements to a flattened `Sequence`, they can be iterated lazily, and the overhead of unnecessary iteration is eliminated. This trick is done by combining `asSequence` and `flatMap`:

```
listOfA.asSequence().flatMap { it.objectBs.asSequence() }.find { it.key == wantedKey }
```

---

I wrote and ran the following code to ensure that it works as expected:

```
class PrintSequenceDelegate<out T>(private val wrappedSequence: Sequence<T>) : Sequence<T> by wrappedSequence {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<T> {
        val wrappedIterator = wrappedSequence.iterator()
        return object : Iterator<T> by wrappedIterator {
            override fun next(): T =
                wrappedIterator.next().also { println("Retrieving: $it") }
        }
    }
}

fun <T> Sequence<T>.toPrintDelegate() = PrintSequenceDelegate(this)

fun main() {
    val listOfLists = List(3) { i -> List(3) { j -> "$i$j" } }
    println("List of lists: $listOfLists")
    val found = listOfLists.asSequence().toPrintDelegate().flatMap { it.asSequence().toPrintDelegate() }.find { it == "11" }
    println(if (found != null) "Found: $found" else "Not found")
}
```

Output:

```
List of lists: [[00, 01, 02], [10, 11, 12], [20, 21, 22]]
Retrieving: [00, 01, 02]
Retrieving: 00
Retrieving: 01
Retrieving: 02
Retrieving: [10, 11, 12]
Retrieving: 10
Retrieving: 11
Found: 11
```

Thus we see that the elements (`12`) after the element found in the containing nested list are not iterated, neither are the following nested lists (`[20, 21, 22]`).

Answer (score 3):

Nothing fancy, but it does the job efficiently:

```
fun findBWithKey(listOfA: List<ObjectA>, wantedKey: String): ObjectB? {
  listOfA.forEach { 
        it.objectBs.forEach { item ->        
             if(item.key == wantedKey){
                 return item
             }
        } 
    }

    return null
}
```

I also like to use `map` and `first`, but doing the given task efficiently gets unecessary hard using those extension functions.

Answer (score 0):

A simple `flatMap` does the trick:

```
listOfA.flatMap { it.objectBs }.first { it.key == wantedKey }
```

This will basically give you an intermediate List with all of them combined so that you can easily query the first matching one.

Comment: This will traverse all items, and the OP is concerned about efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

I like extension functions like this one:

```
inline fun <T, K> List<T>.findInner(find: (T) -> K?): K? {
    forEach {
        val result = find(it)
        if(result != null) return result
    }
    return null
}
```

Iterates any list and returns the first object you found (not null).

Use it like

```
listOfA.findInner {
        if(it.key == wantedKey) it.key else null
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would look in to [coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines-overview.html) or [sequences](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.sequences/index.html) if performance is critical.

You can optimize your code slightly by using firstOrNull on listOfA as well:

```
listOfA.filterNotNull().firstOrNull { item ->
    item.objectBs.firstOrNull { it.key == wantedKey } != null
}
```

I would do some performance testing to see if this code is causing any issues before making it overly complex.

Comment: That code would return ObjectA though, not ObjectB, if I'm seeing this correctly.